# It appears that my function isn't setting a variable publically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The `StreamWriter` in the `Adjust` method creates a text file titled ".txt". I intend for the file to be titled with the `TextInput` passed into `Process`.

After debugging it appears that `ProcessInput` is the correct value at the end of `Process`, but blank at the beginning of `Adjust`.

```
public class Brain : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject Output, Input, AdjustDbInput;
    string ProcessInput;

    public void Process (Text TextInput) 
    {
        ProcessInput = TextInput.text;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Application.dataPath + "/" + ProcessInput + ".txt"))
            Output.GetComponent<Text>().text = 
                System.IO.File.ReadAllText($"{Application.dataPath}/{ProcessInput}.txt");
        else
        {
            Input.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            AdjustDbInput.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    public void Adjust (Text Response) 
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(${Application.dataPath}/{ProcessInput}.txt");
        writer.WriteLine(Response.text);
        writer.Close();
        Input.gameObject.SetActive (true);
        AdjustDbInput.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you use the string variable/field `ProcessInput` for generating the file name. This field is being set in the `Process` method. Is `Process` realling being executed before calling the Adjust method? Also note that `ProcessInput` is an instance field of `Brain`. Which leads me to my next question: When you call `Adjust`, do you call it on exactly the same `Brain` object instance on which you called the `Process` method?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, Adjust is called after Process. As for your other question I am not sure, but I will check when I’m able too.